# How many of the world's workers are producing luxury vs necessary goods?

Tags: reference-request, labor-economics, inequality

Has there been any scholarship done on the proportion of producers producing high-end vs low-end goods? This could also be framed as the proportion of economic activity generated by wealth excess of a certain amount per person. Or is there a better way to understand this issue?

Comment: Good question, but I think it's almost impossible to answer satisfactorily. Many if not most of workers do not produce final goods but intermediate or primary goods, which are used in a variety of final goods (e.g. a tomato producer sells to both high-end restaurants and supermarkets). There are also important conceptual issues with differentiating between necessary and luxury goods. Is a smartphone or a sandwich in the cornershop a luxury good? Is education a necessary good? And a long etc.

Comment: in terms of the mainstream it doesn't really matter as long as what gets produced reflects relative scarcities; perhaps you'd be interested in the classical distinction between [productive and unproductive labor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productive_and_unproductive_labour)